# How do I find out the perimeter of a triangle with 3D vectors?

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to learn more about geometry and vectors and I'm lost with an proposed problem.

I have the following [triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVBJD.png:) coordinates:

$A = (0,1/2,3/2)$

$B = (1,1,0)$

$C = (1,0,1)$

How can I calculate the perimeter of the triangle ABC ?

Should I add the vertices of the triangle like this?

$AB: \sqrt{(0-1)^2+(1/2-1)^2+(3/2-0)^2}$

$BC: \sqrt{(1-1)^2+(1-0)^2+(0-1)^2}$

$CA: \sqrt{(1-0)^2+(0-1/2)^2+(1-3/2)^2}$

And how can I calculate the value of the internal angle of $C$?

Comment: Yes, that's how you find the lengths of the sides. For the angle, have you tried the law of cosines?

Comment: Do you know about dot products of vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use vectors, find vectors $\vec CB$ and $\vec CA$: 
The components of $\vec CB$ are $ (0,1,-1)$, $\vec CA$ are $ (-1,0.5,0.5)$. Then you can find length (magnitude) of the vectors, i.e. : $||CB||=\sqrt{0^2+1^2+(-1)^2}$. 
To find cosine of the angle C, use the law of cosines: $$\cos C=\frac{\vec CA \cdot \vec CB}{||CA||\cdot ||CB||}$$ where $\vec CA \cdot \vec CB=0\cdot(-1)+1\cdot0.5+(-1)\cdot0.5=0$ is the "dot" product.